# Creating packets of data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I'd like to create a packets of data in MySQL. 
Each packet should contains 3 t-shirts: one red and 2 non red t-shirts.

My table looks like:

```
ID, product, packet_number
1, red t-shirt,
2, red t-shirt,
3, blue t-shirt,
4, green t-shirt,
5, blue t-shirt,
6, blue t-shirt,
7, blue t-shirt,
8, green t-shirt,
9, red t-shirt,
```

What i'd like to get:

```
ID, product, packet_number
1, red t-shirt,#1
2, red t-shirt,#2
3, blue t-shirt,#1
4, green t-shirt,#1
5, blue t-shirt,#2
6, blue t-shirt,#2
7, blue t-shirt,#3
8, green t-shirt,#3
9, red t-shirt,#3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this would require a simulated row number (i.e. a ton of work).  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: I tried to select one red t-shirt, and then two non red t-shirts with highest ID but.. there might be a situation when there will not be any red t-shirt  available, but each packaet still should contain 3 t-shirts. The most important thing is: when there is available red t-shirt, it should be in a packet.

Comment: I disagree with Tim. In fact, if the ids really are incremental then it's a piece of cake

Comment: teach me master!